# RestAssured: Can I specify the oauth setting in the Configuration class?

Tags: java, oauth, rest-assured

I am using the RestAssured library in java.

I have the below config class:

```
        import io.restassured.RestAssured;
        import org.junit.BeforeClass;
        import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

        public class TestConfig {

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup(){

            APICredentials ac = new APICredentials();
            RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com";
            RestAssured.basePath = "/1.1/";
            }
        }
```

and then i have a test class which inherit from the config class:

```
    import org.junit.Test;
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

    public class MyFirstTest extends TestConfig{

        @Test
        public void getUserInfo() {
            APICredentials ac = new APICredentials();
            given().
                    log().all().
                    auth().oauth(ac.getConsumer_key(),ac.getConsumer_secret(),ac.getAccess_token(),ac.getToken_secret()).
            when().
                    get("/users/show.json?screen_name=DexisKenway").then().statusCode(200);
        }

    }
```

This test is working well. However, I must repeat the below code in every single test.

```
    APICredentials ac = new APICredentials();
            given().
                    log().all().
                    auth().oauth(ac.getConsumer_key(),ac.getConsumer_secret(),ac.getAccess_token(),ac.getToken_secret()).
```

**I am looking for a solution to add the authentication part into the** ***TestConfig*** **class, so that, I do not need to repeat my code every time** Here is my solution:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup(){

    APICredentials ac = new APICredentials();
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com";
    RestAssured.basePath = "/1.1/";
    RestAssured.given().
                        log().all().
                        auth().oauth(ac.getConsumer_key(),ac.getConsumer_secret(),ac.getAccess_token(),ac.getToken_secret());

}
```

But, **then my request fails with a 400 code**!

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try with following code:

```
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public class TestConfig {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup(){

        APICredentials ac = new APICredentials();


        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setBaseUri("https://api.twitter.com")
                .setBasePath("/1.1/")
                .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .addHeader("Accept","application/json")
                .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
                .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                .build();
        requestSpecification.auth().oauth(ac.getConsumer_key(),ac.getConsumer_secret(),ac.getAccess_token(),ac.getToken_secret());
        RestAssured.requestSpecification = requestSpecification;




    }
}
```

I hope it will solve your issue

Comment: How can i add the `oauth` to the `requestSpecification`?

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your suggestion thanks @Jeff